# How can I change the default template files for c-support?

Tags: plugin-c.vim

I started using c-support recently. When I open a c file, some predefined lines are added automatically to it along with `#define <stdlib.h>` line. I want to modify this default template. I searched for help regarding c-support inside vim (`:help csupport`) but I couldn't understand how to change the default template file. I doubt that help talks of templates which can be added by shortcuts but not the one I want to modify. Any help on this?

Comment: You should give a look at `:help template-support-intro`

Comment: I didn't understand which file to edit and what to edit. Can you give me some more hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After peeking through some files inside the directories the plugin I found a file named `c.comments.template` inside `c-support` directory. Inside this file, the predefined skeleton (which is added everytime a new C file is created) exists. In that file search for `#include<stdlib.h>` and replace it with `#include<stdio.h>` .

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark.